# Unable to install Latte-Dock on Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma

Tags: apt, 18.04, kde, plasma

I have been trying to install Latte Dock on Ubuntu with KDE Plasma, I keep getting errors with unmet dependencies. I tried removing the old packages but that removes the entirety of KDE Plasma. Any help?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 latte-dock : Depends: libkf5declarative5 (>= 5.45.0) but 5.44.0-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
              Depends: libkf5waylandclient5 (>= 4:5.47.0) but 4:5.44.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I tried the solutions in that thread, 1. sudo apt-get autoremove 2. sudo apt-get update and even aptitude (still did not install) and synaptic (no errors).

Comment: @Kulfy I fixed it actually. I added the kubuntu-ppa and tried updating everything. This fixed the issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding the KUbuntu Backports PPA and doing an update. This updated the packages which were outdated.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

This updated all the packages (many) and the installed Latte through the KDE Store.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to fix all broken packages you have with:

```
apt install -f
```

Comment: Yes did just now, still the same error.